# Method introduced in java 9 is compiled using compiler target java 8

Tags: java, maven, java-11

I'm experiencing an odd behavior in maven as well as in eclipse itself. 
Even though i configured my project to be compiled in Java 1.8, I can compile and run (eclipse) a piece of code that was introduced in Java 9

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

The code line in question:

```
LocalTime.ofInstant(cal.toInstant(), cal.getTimeZone().toZoneId());
```

I'm using Oracle's JDK 11 locally for compiling and running in eclipse without any errors. When i package it into a docker container using openjdk:8-jdk-alpine it will boot up, but throw the following Exception when I call the method:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.time.LocalTime.ofInstant(Ljava/time/Instant;Ljava/time/ZoneId;)Ljava/time/LocalTime
```

How can I avoid and identify these situations before they go to testing? Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in the build system or in JDK11?

thanks in advance

Comment: as per the question, your docker container has jdk version 8, ofInstant method is available in jdk 9+. My solution would be try using `openjdk 9 and above` to package.

Comment: hey @josepraveen thanks for your comment. yeah that was my point. maybe i should've noted that currently i cannot update to a higher jdk version. but my question is why i could compile a java 9 code using java 1.8 compiler target and why it would let me run locally.

Comment: The resulting class files are compatible with java 8, but not all of the classes are available. Essentially you're using a two different classpaths for building and running. The java 8 version would work on java 8 if you had the correct library included. If you had compiled to target java 9 then you cannot run the resulting classfiles on an 8 jvm.

Comment: Don’t know the maven syntax, but when compiling with JDK 11 `javac`, to target an older version, you would have to specify the `--release` option.

Comment: @Holger the Maven syntax is in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source option specifies that the source code must be compatible with Java 8, the target option that the classes should be compatible with Java 8. However, you will still compile with the Java 11 class library if you build with Java 11 and then you can get errors like the one you have.

There are two good solutions. One is to use the Maven toolchains plugin and build with Java 8. Then you can have multiple Java versions installed and Maven will use the configured one on a per-project basis.

The other is to use the new release and testRelease options. They will build with API classes from the given release. Just add `<release>1.8</release>`.

Comment: Hi thank you for the hint. i followed your direction and did a little more research and indeed there has been a change for property options (https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-version). i changed my pom to the following:
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>
now i get the compiling error i was expecting

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JDK 11, configure your maven `pom.xml` like that:

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```